# gsub caching groups?

Tags: ruby, pseudo-globals

If I run this code:

```
"Retailer Staff $5.60".gsub(/.*\$(\d+(\.\d+)?).*/, $1)
# => 5.60
```

and then I change the value to:

```
"Retailer Staff $5".gsub(/.*\$(\d+(\.\d+)?).*/, $1)
# => 5.60
```

the answer stays at `5.60`. Then, if I run the same line again, I get:

```
"Retailer Staff $5".gsub(/.*\$(\d+(\.\d+)?).*/, $1)
# => 5
```

What's happening? Why would the same code run twice give two answers? Is `gsub` caching something?

Comment: If you're looking to extract values, consider using `scan` instead of `gsub`.

Comment: To fetch the amount use `"Retailer Staff $5.60"[/\$(\d+(\.\d+)?)/, 1]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is happening because `$1` actually is a global reference to the first capturing group found in the last regular expression that was processed: [ruby 2.4 docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Special+global+variables). So in your case you probably had already tested the regex and matched on "5.60". Here is an annotated snippet that I ran in ruby 2.0:

```
# Since no regex has executed yet $1 is nil
irb(main):001:0> "Retailer Staff $5.60".gsub(/.*\$(\d+(\.\d+)?).*/, $1)
TypeError: no implicit conversion of nil into String
    from (irb):1:in 'gsub'
    from (irb):1
    from /usr/bin/irb:12:in '<main>'
irb(main):002:0> "Retailer Staff $5.60".gsub(/.*\$(\d+(\.\d+)?).*/, 'some value')
=> "some value"
irb(main):003:0> $1   # Now we have executed a regex so $1 is set
=> "5.60"             
irb(main):004:0> "Retailer Staff $5.60".gsub(/.*\$(\d+(\.\d+)?).*/, $1) 
=> "5.60"
irb(main):005:0> $1   # This is still the same value because we matched the same string
=> "5.60"             
irb(main):006:0> "Retailer Staff $5".gsub(/.*\$(\d+(\.\d+)?).*/, $1)
=> "5.60"
irb(main):007:0> $1   # Now we have matched the 5 so $1 has the new value
=> "5"                
irb(main):008:0> "Retailer Staff $5".gsub(/.*\$(\d+(\.\d+)?).*/, $1)
=> "5"
irb(main):009:0> $1
=> "5"
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesn't really make sense and it doesn't do what you think it does.

`$1` is a global variable so the first `gsub` will replace the matched pattern with whatever was in `$1` *before* you called `gsub`. This:

```
"Retailer Staff $5.60".gsub(/.*\$(\d+(\.\d+)?).*/, $1)
```

is equivalent to:

```
confusion = $1
"Retailer Staff $5.60".gsub(/.*\$(\d+(\.\d+)?).*/, confusion)
```

when you really mean to say:

```
"Retailer Staff $5.60".gsub(/.*\$(\d+(\.\d+)?).*/) { $1 }
```

so that `gsub` can set `$1` before yielding to the block.

Once you understand when `$1` is set and when it is being evaluated then everything else falls into place. Your first `gsub` ends up setting `$1` to `'5.60'` and then your next call is just an overcomplicated way of saying:

```
"Retailer Staff $5".gsub(/.*\$(\d+(\.\d+)?).*/, '5.60')
```

and it sets `$1` to `'5'`. And so on.